# Why does my html web not extend the background and show parts in white?

Tags: html, css

I want my web to have a full background with no white parts or blank parts, I have tried several codes and stuff but none seems to work well.

The background image that I have is not on the internet but is instead offline and only available in my desktop because I edited it, so I can only use the commands background-image or body background with my own files (I thought that would be important to know if someone wanted to help me with the code)

My web is this one:

[![Background I use][1]][1]

[![Issue][2]][2]

[![EDIT with suggested code][3]][3]

The whole code is:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/18f289db08.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
</html>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="author" content="Iván Camacho"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<style>

body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-attachment:local;
background-image: url("2022-03-08\ \(3\).png");
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="Negro3">
        <img src="Fondo_Negro - copia.jpg" width="270" height="310">
        </div> 

<div class="Negro2">
    <img src="Fondo_Negro - copia (2).jpg" width="270" height="310">
     </div>    

<div class="Negro1">
<img src="Fondo_Negro.jpg" width="270" height="310">
</div>
    
<div class="superscript">
<i class="fa fa-superscript" style="font-size:60px;color:white;"></i>
</div>

<div class="calculator">
    <i class="fa fa-calculator" style="font-size:60px;color:white;"></i>
</div>

<div class="flask">
    <i class="fa fa-flask" style="font-size:60px;color:white;"></i>
</div>  

    <div class="Sciencestudio">
    <h1> Science studio </h1>
    </div>
<p>  <a href="https://google.es"> google link </a> <img src="https://www.google.com/search?q=imagen&rlz=1C1CAFB_enES711ES711&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBudns5aT2AhVDrxoKHVc9DR8Q_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1242&bih=568&dpr=1.1#imgrc=GEeCSbujNt4WcM"/>  cuerpo </p>

<div class="Matemáticas"> <p2> <a href="file:///C:/Users/xtrem/OneDrive/Escritorio/TICO%20Web%20Iv%C3%A1n%20Camacho%20Moya/Matem%C3%A1ticas.html" style="color:aliceblue"> MATEMÁTICAS </a> </p2> </div>
<div class="FÍSICA"> <p2> <a href="file:///C:/Users/xtrem/OneDrive/Escritorio/TICO%20Web%20Iv%C3%A1n%20Camacho%20Moya/F%C3%ADsica.html" style="color:aliceblue"> FÍSICA </a> </p2> </div>
<div class="QUÍMICA"> <p2> <a href="file:///C:/Users/xtrem/OneDrive/Escritorio/TICO%20Web%20Iv%C3%A1n%20Camacho%20Moya/Qu%C3%ADmica.html" style="color:aliceblue"> QUÍMICA </a> </p2> </div>

</body>


</html>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwWjx.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/13g0M.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQLZc.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry but we can't see your local drive `C:/Users/...`. Please provide reproducible example (code).

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away, is fixed, or **can't be accessed because we aren't sitting at your PC**. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: yes I've just added the relevant code, do I need to upload the whole? And the CSS code too?

Answer (score 1):

You have `contain` for `background-size` which makes sure that image is fully visible. You want to use `cover` which fills whole space.

> **contain**
> Scales the image as large as possible within its container without cropping or stretching the image. If the container is larger than the image, this will result in image tiling, unless the background-repeat property is set to no-repeat.
>
> **cover**
> Scales the image as large as possible to fill the container, stretching the image if necessary. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.
>
> source: [MDN - background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#values)

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.cover {
  background-size: cover;
}
.contain {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
Cover:
<div class="cover"></div>
Contain:
<div class="contain"></div>
```

Comment: somehow this worsened it, let me post the results to the original post with an edit, and maybe also add the full code because maybe that's what's making this all go wrong.

Comment: Using cover works for me using another image. Can you upload your actual image using the SO system and make your code into an SO snippet and see what happens?